# Spring Boot & Spring Security : Issues with mixing roles and authorities for access control

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using Spring Boot 2.7.2 and have set up a security configuration with roles and authorities for my users. However, I'm having issues when mixing roles and authorities in my access control expression.

Here's my configuration:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().access("isAuthenticated() and hasAuthority('read')")
            .and()
            .build();
}

@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(){
    InMemoryUserDetailsManager udm = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
    UserDetails ud = User.withUsername("bill")
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode("password"))
            .authorities("read")
            .roles("MANAGER")
            .build();

    UserDetails ud1 = User.withUsername("john")
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode("password"))
            .authorities("write")
            .roles("ADMIN")
            .build();

    udm.createUser(ud);
    udm.createUser(ud1);

    return udm;
}
```

With this configuration, both users are rejected when trying to access an endpoint. However, if I remove the roles and only use authorities when creating users, it works fine: bill can access the endpoint, and john cannot.

With this configuration it will work as expected:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().access("isAuthenticated() and hasAuthority('read')")
            .and()
            .build();
}

@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(){
    InMemoryUserDetailsManager udm = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
    UserDetails ud = User.withUsername("bill")
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode("password"))
            .authorities("read")
            .build();

    UserDetails ud1 = User.withUsername("john")
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode("password"))
            .authorities("write")
            .build();

    udm.createUser(ud);
    udm.createUser(ud1);

    return udm;
}
```

I would like to understand why this issue occurs when I mix roles and authorities and how I can make it work with both roles and authorities in my configuration. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the construction of your `User`.

```java
UserDetails ud = User.withUsername("bill")
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode("password"))
            .authorities("read")
            .roles("MANAGER")
            .build();
```

If you would have checked the code for the [`User`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.java), or rather the [`UserBuilder`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.java#L326) and the corresponding [`authorities`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.java#L411) and [`roles`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.java#L456) methods you will see that each replaces the full authorities. So you use either one or the other.

If you look even closer you will see that both `authorities` and `roles` are actually just `authorities`. The only difference is that the `roles` are going to be prefixed with `ROLE_`.

So in your initial setup you are ending up with just 1 authority named `ROLE_MANAGER` / `ROLE_ADMIN` and not your `read` authority.

Instead of calling both methods, just call `authorities` with both `read` and `ROLE_MANAGER`.

```java
UserDetails ud = User.withUsername("bill")
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode("password"))
            .authorities("read", "ROLE_MANAGER")
            .build();
```

Comment: That makes sense. 

I was aware that i could declare roles in the authorities method as you suggested, but was not aware that one method would replace the other.